# How to prevent encoding of inner html text in Scalatags render

Tags: scalatags

Say I have a string like this defined:

```
val inner = "<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>"
```

And I want to embed this html using some rendering code along these lines:

```
div(inner).render
```

How to I prevent encoding of the inner part? I want to yield the complete html structure as below:

```
<div><p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p></div>
```

And not:

```
 <div>&lt;p&gt;Paragraph 1&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Paragraph 2&lt;/p&gt;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the raw function to prevent encoding. So the code should read:

```
div(raw(inner)).render
```